# Alternative to file_get_contents and curl to get remote image

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I had a music database PHP-script that automatically gets album-covers from remote server via `file_get_contents`. For some time now, it doesn't work anymore. I tried to do same thing with `curl` and `Gd Library`, but same problem, it returns `"403 - forbidden"`. I guess it´s any type of hotlink protection in remote server, I can open remote image URL in browser, but I can´t grab it to my server.

Is there any alternative to bypass this issue and grab remote image?

Comment: run link directly in the browser once see http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm

Comment: Most hotlink protections work by checking the `user-agent`. You can by pass it by sending a 'right' header with it.

Comment: Try setting fake http referrer or user-agent.

Answer (score 1):

To spoof the `user-agent` and other references in a CURL request you can use this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

This will probably bypass the hotlink protection, it bypasses my own ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to determine which image you need and load that directly to browser.
It will not violate hot-linking. And should work fine.

Comment: I don´t want to load image in browser, I have the image url (Ex: http://www.domain.com/image.jpg) and I want to save it in my server automatically using PHP